# Syntax error near unexpected token `(' when using R system() function

Tags: bash, awk, rscript

Here I have multiple files say 3 files with same rows and columns, now I want to extract the second column from each file and paste them in a new file. When I run the following command in linux bash,its working.

```
paste <(awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}(NR>1){print $2}' text1.txt) <(awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}(NR>1){print $2}' text2.txt) <(awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}(NR>1){print $2}' text3.txt) > output.txt
```

While when I try to use R script to run this command via system() function by

```
cmd = paste0("paste ", paste0("<(awk 'BEGIN{OFS=\"\t\"}(NR>1){print $2}' text", 1:3, ".txt) ", collapse = ""), " > output.txt", collapse = "")
system(cmd)
```

it returns error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can anyone help me out. Appreciate any help.

Comment: system() uses sh, not bash. You can't use `<()` in sh.

Comment: @Charles. Thanks very much for ur reply. Then is it possible to run the command above in R?

Comment: My expertise is in bash, not R. Unfortunately, https://ro-che.info/articles/2020-12-11-r-system2 indicates that at least as of late 2020, R didn't provide anything that was a close equivalent to the `execve()` or `posix_spawn()` calls, which are what you'd want here to do this right.

Comment: That said, reading the actual code, you don't really _need_ bash-only syntax for it. Justaminute, and I'll throw together an answer compatible with `sh`.

Comment: Please explain why you must use assembly of linux commands rather than single call to `awk` or `R` abilities of text processing

Comment: Thank you all. Now I understand the reason why this occur as suggested (system() use sh rather than bash while <(...) is a bash feature). So, in R, I try to write these commands in a separate bash script, and then use system("bash script.bash"), which works well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<()` is only available in extended shells (ksh93, bash, zsh, etc); and `system()` uses `sh`. However, you can write an equivalent script that works with `sh`:

```
while read _ a _ <&3 && read _ b _ <&4 && read _ c _ <&5; do
  printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
done 3<text1.txt 4<text2.txt 5<text3.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I write these commands in a separate bash script, and then use system("bash script.bash"), which works well now.